# How to find documents

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Below is the mongoose code in app.js

```
app.get('/view', function (req, res) {


if (err) return handleError(err);

    {
```

);
    });

I have two different host entries that is Host_name:Redhat1,Host_name:Redhat2.
How to get only latest entries of both using mongoose.
What should be modified in the above find condition in schema. Please help

Comment: Need more description

Comment: you need latest entries of both  Redhat1,Redhat2  right ?

Comment: Find by `Host_Name` (one query for each name), order `desc` by the timestamp and limit to 1.

Comment: you can do as @ ShanShan stated but there is another good way that is grouping the result by Host_name sort by time stamp and limit 2

Comment: @AlokDeshwal the grouping could have unexpected result, the first name's two latest entries can be at the top when sorting.

Comment: for that we can use distinct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
User.aggregate(
        { $match: { "Host.Host_name": { $in: ["RedHat1", "RedHat2"] }}}
        { $group: { _id: "$Host.Host_name", Time_stamp:{$last:'$Date.Time_stamp'}}}
       ,function (err,docs) {
        if (err) return handleError(err);
                var Users = docs.map(function (User){
                    return {
                        time: User.Time_stamp,
                        host: User._id
                    }
                });
            res.render('index',{Users: Users});
        });
```

Hope this will resolve your problem

Comment: The aggregate works but no need for `$limit`, just add a `$match` before the `$group`. Code: http://pastebin.com/CQnPuBWP

Comment: There was an error so check modified one and it worked

Comment: @ShanShan code creating error for you and my code worked for you right ?

Comment: @ShanShan may you tell me that what is the difference between passing a callback as argument and .exec command

Comment: @ShanShan you din my question's answer

Comment: @joy ya sure . you'll have to add those in group just like Time_stamp

Comment: Which template engine you are using ?

Comment: have a look : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265514/how-do-i-update-a-jade-template-form-an-ajax-post

Comment: use sp1:{$last: '$Speed.cpu_speed'} instead of  sp1: '$Speed.cpu_speed'

Comment: @joy try this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356164/auto-refresh-div-in-jade-template-node-js-express

Comment: @joy possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539955/how-to-paginate-with-mongoose-in-node-js

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way : find by Host_Name (one query for each name), order desc by the timestamp and limit to 1.

```
// needed to tell mongoose to use ES6 Promises
require('mongoose').Promise = global.Promise;

app.get('/view', function (req, res) {
    var query1 = User.find({ "Host.Host_name": "RedHat1" })
        .sort({ Date.Time_stamp: -1 })
        .limit(1)
        .exec(); // exec() without argument returns a promise

    var query2 = User.find({ "Host.Host_name": "RedHat2" })
        .sort({ Date.Time_stamp: -1 })
        .limit(1)
        .exec();

    Promise.all([query1, query2])
        .then(function (docs) {
            var Users = docs.map(function (User){
                return {
                    time: User.Date.Time_stamp,
                    host: User.Host.Host_name
                }
            });
            res.render('index',{Users: Users});
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
});
```

Edit: doing two queries leads to an another issue, you have to wait for both to be complete before sendind a response so I updated my example.

Comment: Corrected few typos. Try `console.log(docs)`, I just tried, it works. `docs` is an array containing two arrays, each of these array contains one document.

Comment: No, it's the standard ES6 promises, it's around for a while. The issue is elsewhere, what version of mongoose are you using? Maybe it's so old it doesn't return a promise (it seems to require a callback for exec).  [Doc for `exec()` function](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-exec).

Comment: Ouch, it's a 4 years old version, you should consider updating if you can.

Comment: But how did you get that old version? How did you install mongoose? Running `npm install mongoose` in your project directory will install the latest version.

Comment: See my comment below to *Alok Deshwal*'s answer, I posted a code that should work.